# JS/JQuery: Redirect on the basis of XML response

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to redirect the user to a certain URL on the basis of what comes out of an `XMLHttpRequest()`? Here's what I am trying to achieve:

1. User hits submit, form gets submitted, `XMLHttpRequest()` fired
2. Response received from the server, stored in `var hr`
3. If `hr` = `abc`, show contents of `hr`
4. If `hr` = `xyz`, redirect user to `http://www.something.com`

What I am looking for is if there's any predesigned method in either JS or JQ to handle such redirects. I understand redirects can be specified in the `<meta>` tags in the `<header>` section of the page but if I did that, how will I be able to add conditions to it? I would have posted a copy of the script I have attempted but can't because right now, I have no idea where to even begin!

In case someone is curious about the scenario, this is a Web-based dictionary/conjugation service. So, on the verb conjugation page, if the user enters a valid verb, the response (i.e. the conjugation tables) is displayed. However, if the user enters a word that's valid but not a verb so it can't be conjugated, I want the user to be automatically redirected to the dictionary page where the entered word's dictionary entry will be displayed. Not sure if I have explained it well enough but please feel free to ask should you have any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try testing with `switch(request.responseText)` and call `window.location.assign("http://your-url.com");` in the preferred case "xyz"! Alternatively `window.open("http://anotherxxxwebsite.com")` opens the link in a new browser window.

Answer (score 1):

There's no "predesigned" method, but you can write that logic yourself. Depending on your current API you could either check if the returned value is an URI (or some other designated value instead) an redirect accordingly. Assuming a deferred object returned from [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

```
defer.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // assuming a string, but this could really be anthing, e.g.
    // an object containing an appropriate attribute, etc.
    if (data.indexOf('http') === 0) {
        window.open(data);
    } else {
        // render your stuff
    }
});
```